# Connecting to Astra DB from pure Spring app, No Spring boot

Tags: spring, reactive, spring-data-cassandra, datastax-astra

I have a spring app (no Spring Boot) which is using spring data cassandra for data access. I want to use reactive version of spring data cassandra and connect to Data stax Astra DB. connecting to Astra DB is through a bundle file. But I don't know how to configure spring and spring data cassandra reactive to do this.